# How to remove top-level pointer from typename?

Tags: c, function, pointers, types

For example if I have:

```
typedef int (*pFuncType)(int a, char b);
```

And I want for ease to declare a function of the type which 'pFuncType' is pointer to. Something like this:

```
(*pFuncType) funcDeclr;
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this even possible?

This is not possible. The declaration

```
typedef int * intptr;
```

means `intptr` is of new type. A new variable of type `intptr` can be defined as

```
intptr p;    // Same as int * p;
```

Using `intptr` it is not possible to declare a variable of type `int`. Doing

```
(*inptr) i;
```

is equivalent to

```
(*(int *)) i;
```

which is a wrong syntax.
The same hold true with `pFuncType`.

Also note that the rule of declaration is that *declation specifier* must comes before the *declarators*. `*` comes in declarators, therefore it can't come before any *declaration specifier*. Look at the [grammar](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/cs48/references/c.html)<sup>1</sup>

```
declaration
    declaration-specifiers ;
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list ;   

declaration-specifiers
    storage-class-specifier
    type-specifier
    type-qualifier
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers
    type-specifier          declaration-specifiers
    type-qualifier          declaration-specifiers

init-declarator-list
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator

init-declarator
    declarator
    declarator = initializer   

......
......

declarator
    direct-declarator
    pointer direct-declarator

direct-declarator
    identifier
    ( declarator )
    direct-declarator [ ]
    direct-declarator [ constant-expression ]
    direct-declarator ( )
    direct-declarator ( parameter-type-list )
    direct-declarator ( identifier-list )

pointer
     *
     * pointer
     * type-qualifier-list
     * type-qualifier-list pointer
```

---

<sub>1 The grammar can be found in C11 standard under the section §6.7 and §6.7.6</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No. You can declare a non-pointer type, though:

```
typedef int (funcType)(int a, char b);

funcType f;

int f(int a, char b) {
    return a;
}
```